# Как лучше и правильно будет задать обработчик клика?

Tags: javascript

Мне надо поставить будет на 2 кнопки и 1 блок событие на клик. И я сделать вот так, но мне кажется повторяю код, или лучше будет поставить один клас на все 2 кнопки и 1 блок, и перебирать их циклом и ставить событие, или есть еще варианты?

```
    const exitMenu = document.querySelector('.exit');
    const pupMenu = document.querySelector('.wrap-pup');
    
    pupMenu.addEventListener('click', exit)
    exitMenu.addEventListener('click', exit)
    
    function exit() {
       pupMenu.classList.add('hide');
       contactMenu.classList.remove('show-pub');
    }
```

полная розметка:

```
 <div class="wrap-pup hide">
      <div class="contact-menu d-flex">
         <div class="exit">
            <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
         </div>

         <div class="left-side">
            <h3 class="contact-menu__title">LET'S TALK!</h3>
            <h2 class="contact-menu__sup-title">CALL ME OR SEND ME A REQUEST</h2>
            <div class="contact-menu__contact-person">
               <div class="contact-menu__phone-text">
                  <i class="fas fa-phone"></i> +380986404004
               </div>
               <div class="contact-menu__email-text">
                  <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> gapachilomaxim@gmail.com
               </div>
            </div>
            <form action="POST">
               <label for="email">
                  Adress e-mail
               </label>
               <input class="contact-menu__email" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Adress e-mail">

               <label for="text">
                  Request
               </label>
               <textarea class="contact-menu__request" name="text" id="text"
                  placeholder="Type your request..."></textarea>

               <div class="contact-menu__wrap-btn">
                  <button class="contact-menu__send" type="submit">SEND</button>
               </div>

            </form>
         </div>
         <div class="rigth-side">
            <div class="contact-menu__wrap-img">
               <img class="contact-menu__img" src="img/request.png" alt="request">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: можно разметку глянуть? если есть возможность делегирования я бы выбрал его

Comment: @DaniilLoban добавил

Comment: И такая еще проблема,  мне надо поставить клык на крестик с классом exit, и на задный фон, но если поставить клык через задный фон то если кликать на любую точку то будет закрывать

Comment: что такое клык? я вижу только одну кнопку... ага понял клик это клык))

Comment: мне надо чтоб событие клика работал на класс exit , и на весь контент где клику кроме класса contact-menu , как лучше сделать?)

Comment: думаю можно оставить как есть 2 события это не сильно загрязняет код и в целом изменения профит не принесут разве что без навешивания событий можно обойтись прописать инлайн

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117792/discussion-between-daniil-loban-and-maksym-gapachilo).